# mat-slide-toggle CAMBIA solo con el renderizado de angular

Tags: angular

Estoy intentando que un mat-slide-toggle el cual tengo inicializado a true, cuando se encuentre a false, se quede guardado ese estado en Angular. Pero pasado un tiempo vuelve a ponerse a true. Es un proyecto el cual no he hecho yo y estoy intentando poner una solución. Este sería el código que uso:

HTML:

```
<ng-template #ocultarImagenes></ng-template>
 <mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="isChecked" 
  (change)="onChangeImages($event,isChecked)">¿Imágenes? 
   </mat-slide-toggle>
    <ng-container *ngIf="(isChecked === true); else ocultarImagenes">
     <ul class="thumnailList">
       <li *ngFor="let thumbnailPath of design.thumbnailrelativefilepaths">
         <img src="{{getThumbnailURL(thumbnailPath)}}" alt="" 
          (click)="openDesignImageDialog(design, thumbnailPath)" class="thumbnailImg">
       </li>
     </ul>
```

```
TS:

export class DesignComponent implements OnInit {

isChecked = true;
public lastEdited: string;

 onChangeImages(event: any, isChecked){
    
    if(isChecked === false){
          isChecked = false;
          event.value = isChecked;
          isChecked = localStorage.setItem('LastEditedName', isChecked);
          isChecked = localStorage.getItem('LastEditedName');
          this.lastEdited = localStorage.getItem('LastEditedName');
          isChecked = this.lastEdited;
          console.log("Hola compruebo ischecked: " + isChecked);
          
   
  }else{
          isChecked = true;
          event.value = isChecked;
          isChecked = localStorage.setItem('LastEditedName', isChecked);
          isChecked = localStorage.getItem('LastEditedName');
          this.lastEdited = localStorage.getItem('LastEditedName');
          isChecked = this.lastEdited;
          console.log("Hola compruebo ischecked 2.0: " + isChecked);
      
  }

 }




Gracias
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sin entrar en otros temas, bien te han indicado, no pases como parametro una propiedad de la clase.

```html
<ng-template #ocultarImagenes></ng-template>
 <mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="isChecked" 
  (change)="onChangeImages($event,isChecked)">¿Imágenes?
   </mat-slide-toggle>
    <ng-container *ngIf="(isChecked === true); else ocultarImagenes">
     <ul class="thumnailList">
       <li *ngFor="let thumbnailPath of design.thumbnailrelativefilepaths">
         <img src="{{getThumbnailURL(thumbnailPath)}}" alt="" 
          (click)="openDesignImageDialog(design, thumbnailPath)" class="thumbnailImg">
       </li>
     </ul>
```

aqui solo pasa el evento, en vez de : `(change)="onChangeImages($event,isChecked)"`

simplemente: `(change)="onChangeImages($event)"`

y el en ts, deberias simplificar las veces que asignas contenido a la propiedad `isChecked` y sobre todo que valores le esta asignando.

```js
export class DesignComponent implements OnInit {

  //isChecked = true; //cambiamos esto e intentamos obtener el valor del localStorage
  public isChecked: any;
  public lastEdited: string;

  ngOnInit(){
    this.isChecked = localStorage.getItem('isChecked');
    if(this.isChecked){
      this.isChecked = this.isChecked == 'true'? true : false
    }
    .....
  }    
  //onChangeImages(event: any, isChecked){ esta linea la cambiamos para recibir solo el evento
  onChangeImages(event: any){

  /*  todo lo que aparece en este if esta duplicado y no lo necesitas para cambiar la propiedad "isChecked"

      if(isChecked === false){
            isChecked = false;
            event.value = isChecked;
            isChecked = localStorage.setItem('LastEditedName', isChecked);
            isChecked = localStorage.getItem('LastEditedName');
            this.lastEdited = localStorage.getItem('LastEditedName');
            isChecked = this.lastEdited;
            console.log("Hola compruebo ischecked: " + isChecked);


    }else{
            isChecked = true;
            event.value = isChecked;
            isChecked = localStorage.setItem('LastEditedName', isChecked);
            isChecked = localStorage.getItem('LastEditedName');
            this.lastEdited = localStorage.getItem('LastEditedName');
            isChecked = this.lastEdited;
            console.log("Hola compruebo ischecked 2.0: " + isChecked);

    }

  podrias simplemente chequear el evento y setear la propiedad con el valor que traiga el evento:
  */

    if(event.checked  === false){ //es decir, si el evento trae valor 'false'
      this.isChecked = false
    }else{
      this.isChecked = true
    }
  //el resto de operaciones las haces igualmente, sea true o false  
    localStorage.setItem('LastEditedName', this.isChecked);
    this.lastEdited = localStorage.getItem('LastEditedName');
    //agregamos el valor que ha tomado this.isChecked al localStorage:
    localStorage.setItem('isChecked', this.isChecked);
  }

}
```

las demas operaciones que no pongo, hasta donde yo veo, no son necesarias, y algunas diria que incorrectas.
de este modo solo modificas una vez la propiedad y evitas errores que puede generar tanta asignacion de valores diferentes a una variable que ni siquiera es la propiedad de la clase

***edicion***
teniendo en cuenta que los datos que se recuperan de localStorage son siempre tipo string, si en algun momento recuperas el valor de `this.lastEdited = localStorage.getItem('LastEditedName');`, la propiedad `this.lastEdited` sera
"true" o "false" y no `true` o `false`.

espero que esto te ayude.

Comment: Gracias, pero sigue pasando lo mismo. Necesito algo que bloquee el renderizado y que la propiedad no cambie. Aunque sea poco hortodoxo....

Comment: quiza nos falte algo mas de codigo, las correcciones que te propongo no deberian permitir que se cambie el <mat-slide-toggle>, yo lo uso bastante.

Comment: en alguna parte del codigo puede que se modifique el valor de la propiedad, te modifico la respuesta con una correccion para buscar el valor en el localStorage directamente y tomar su valor al inicio, por si recargases el componente de algun modo tener siempre el mismo valor.

Comment: Gracias, funcionó. Muy agradecido

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes una propiedad en la clase que se llama isChecked, no la pases como parámetro a los métodos. Si intentas cambiar el valor del parámetro, no se reflejará en la propiedad:

```js
export class DesignComponent implements OnInit {

  isChecked = true;
  public lastEdited: string;

   onChangeImages(event: any){
     if (this.isChecked) {
       ...
     } else {
       ...
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar. Vuelve a cambiar el mat-slide-toggle